# When can I take additional actions in Grand Austria Hotel?

Tags: grand-austria-hotel

The [rules](http://lookout-spiele.de/wp-content/uploads/GAH_rules_EN_web.pdf) for Grand Austria Hotel contain this section:

> **On your turn, you take the following actions:**
>
> 1. Take a guest from the game board. (optional)
> 2. Take a die and carry out the corresponding action. (mandatory)
>
> You can also take **additional** actions (see “Additional Actions”).

It does not seem clear whether additional actions have to be taken after step 2, as part of step 2, or if they can be taken at any point during the turn.

For example is it possible to pay a krone to move dishes onto a guest and then move the guest to a free room, so that you have a table free to take a new guest (step 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of the games designers clarified this on [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25054094#25054094), but you can take an additional action at any time during your turn, with the caveat that in order to increase the number on a die you must have the needed Krone when you take the die.

Page 8 of the [rulebook](http://lookout-spiele.de/wp-content/uploads/GAH_rules_EN_web.pdf) contains the unorder list of "Additional Actions".

[image: Additional Actions]